# how to read item from dynamoDb in aws?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I got error when try to read item from dynamodb by using getItem()

This is my code snippet:

```
DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(new AmazonDynamoDBClient(new ProfileCredentialsProvider()));  
Table table = dynamoDB.getTable("ProductList");  
Item item = table.getItem("IDnum", 109);
```

i got error like attribute mismatch

Comment: Need to improve formatting.

Comment: Is `IDnum` the primary key of this table?

Answer (score 0):

The code you are sharing comes from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dynamodb/dynamodb_getting_items.html. It works as expected, ensure that you are passing the correct partition key name for your table.

```
public Item getItem(String hashKeyName,
                    Object hashKeyValue)
```

[Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/Table.html#getItem-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-)